# excel count if text values separated by comma

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i have a column that was use to store multiple answer question, the answers are displayed separated by comma, example:

[image]

I need to know the number of responses of each word separated by comma like this:

[image]

I tried : `=COUNTIF(RANGE:RANGE,"FACEBOOK")` but it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any array formula. Use `Wildcard` to count part of string. Try following formula.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*FACEBOOK*")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this array formula:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(SEARCH(E1,$A$1:$A$8),0)>0))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=COUNT(SEARCH("Facebook",RANGE))
```